# UIDocument & NSFileWrapper with many small files crashes due to low memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocument, nsfilewrapper

I have a custom `UIDocument` consisting of a file package with many small files (about 3200 text files). The overall size of the document is only ~600KB, but my app crashes each time I attempt to open the document due to low memory.

I tracked it down to the place where UIDocument tries to map the folder to an `NSFileWrapper`.

The document is displayed in a table, so at the most I would need to load only 20 files from the file package at once.

Is there a way to only "partially" load an `NSFileWrapper` or some other form of lazy loading (I'm not talking about memory mapping, since the problem is about many small files)?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this issue?

Comment: See [this link](https://github.com/lukescott/LSFileWrapper). It looks like an attempt to resolve this exact issue...might be worth a try.

Comment: I did not find a solution for this issue. I changed my document design to use fewer files.

Comment: thanks @mark...it seems like this is what I will possibly need to do...

Comment: If the fileWrapper has memory problem, what about only saving useful infomations (as string or other object) that will be shown in the tableView?

Comment: It seems caused by holding many FileWrapper object at one time, what about change to holding the obj as other type, and using FileWrapper only in file edit operations?